# Ionic 2 Firebase Cloud Messaging Notifications - Xcode says Connected to FCM, but message never comes through

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've gotten my Ionic 2 app configured, Firebase Cloud Messaging, configured, and when I install my Ionic app onto my phone, I don't get any errors. In fact, my log says `Connected to FCM`.

The problem is that when I log into my Firebase console and navigate to Notifications -> New message, I create a "New Message" with the target set as "User Segment" with my iOS app selected. and when I click "Send Message", my device never receives the app even when I've got the app running. And my log doesn't say anything beyond the "Connected to FCM" like it did when I installed the app.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Stevie. Do post the relevant code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I realized there was a whole step I was forgetting to get setup with Firebase but after going through the documentation here, I was able to send notifications: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of potential firebase messaging errors and the console doesn't give any return info. Testing with a curl is a lot better:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key=<your key from the firebase console> -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "notification": {
    "title": "Yo friend says",
    "body": "Pay attention to me",
  },
  "to": <firebase instance id>
}' "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
```